# Unable to perform an action on none of elements of an application screen

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, onclick, element

The application I am trying to test using selenium has a login page which moves to the next menu page after login. The new page opens on a new IE window which closes the previous window. I have confirmed that the focus is on the new window using the winhandler and printing out the URL by getUrl. even though the focus is on the correct screen, Selenium is not able to perform any action on the screen.

So far I have tested the following methods,

1. Frame handler
2. Winhandler for window focus
3. Get element id by all possible means like id, class,linktext,xpath
   etc

**Error message** 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Inquiries & Reports"}

Please shed some light on what could be the solution.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add code samples to demonstrate this problem? Check out this link for guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Pardon me, since i will not be able to share specific code samples. I can assure that the code has no error before execution.

Comment: The application i am trying to automate test is an intranet site. For the issue i have mentioned above, i took the following approach

Comment: 1. verify focus is on the required window 2. verify focus is on the frame which has the element i want to find.      3. search the element by all possible ways of By.<options>        available                                                                                                       There has been success in the 1st and 2nd steps mentioned above, but the step three is failing.